# Gnuplot: how to set pm3d map transparent?

Tags: gnuplot

I have really simple question: I would like to know how to make the contour figure (pm3d map) transparent in Gnuplot (gnuplot version 5.2).

I could find ways to make transparent plots or filled curve,
(such as this website - http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/transparent.html)
but not for the contour plots.

What I am trying to do is, to overlay image and contour plot and would like to make the contour transparent.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

**Added:**
When I try to do

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
```

the contour region changed to gray.. why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question... do you really need `splot` and `pm3d`?
Maybe the following is also a practicable solution just with `plot ... with boxxyerror`. Probably, it can be optimized further.

**Input:** "MapTest.png"
[image]

**Code:**

```
### map with transparent overlay
reset session
set term pngcairo size 700,700 font ",10"
set output "MapTransparent.png"
set size square
set margins 0,0,0,0
unset tics
set cbtics
unset key

# function "borrowed" from http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/07/maps-contour-plots-with-labels.html
f(x,y)=(sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))*3+15
set samples 51
set isosamples 51
set table $Data
    splot [0:600][0:600] f(x/60.,y/60.)
unset table
# create contour lines
set contour base
set cntrparam levels 10
unset surface
set table $Contour
    splot [0:600][0:600] f(x/60.,y/60.)
unset table

set xrange[0:600]
set yrange[0:600]
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10

set style fill transparent solid 0.4 noborder
plot \
    "MapTest.png" binary filetype=png w rgbimage, \
    $Data u 1:2:(6):(6):3 with boxxyerror palette,\
    $Contour u 1:2:3 w l lt rgb "grey"

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a global style setting that affects all filled objects in gnuplot including the quadrangles that make up a pm3d surface.   To set 50% transparency:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
```

This only applies to the area-fill, however, not to the edges.  If you want the surface overall to be transparent it is best not to draw the edges:

```
set pm3d noborder
```

Note: I am not sure how "contour plot" fits into this.  Contour lines are something else. You could set them to be transparent also, but that would not affect the pm3d surface per se.

Here is a surface drawn as "splot ... with pm3d" before and after setting the fill style to transparent.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! but the contour plot changes to gray if we set "transparent solid 0.5".... why?

Comment: Weird.  What terminal type are you using?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer! Yes, it is weird. I was able to reproduce your result in the interactive command-line gnuplot. but I cannnot reproduce with my gnuplot script.... in this script, I am exporting to png file.

Comment: Ok, now I solved the problem... when I changed from png to jpeg (underlying image was jpeg), it worked! (I still do not understand what is going on). This is weird because it didn't cause trouble to create contour plot in png.